# When a nodejs callback will be called an unknown number of times and you need to do something after the last one

Tags: node.js

As I understand it, the node-netstat package parses the output of the netstat command and it calls the callback I supply, once per line of data it parses.

I could do with knowing when it's made its last call, so I know to callback the function that was supplied to my function by elsewhere, but I'm not really sure how to do this..

```
this.myfunc = function(callback){

  netstat(null, function(data){
    //netstat will call this function X times. I'd like to accumulate data
  });

  callback( ..data from netstat.. );

}
```

If netstat's callback only fired  once, with all the data, then I could probably have called callback at the end of `function(data)`, but the multi-calls is confounding that. What do we do in situations like this? (Note also, it's a really prehistoric version of node: 0.10.24)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an `option` object to `netstat(options, handler)` function.

In `option` object, there is a `done` field which you can pass a callback function.

More information about `option` object can be found [here](https://github.com/danielkrainas/node-netstat#readme)